# Recent change of Google Drive API from "sensitive" to "restricted" scope, and it's effect of app already verified previously

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mobile, google-api, google-oauth, verification

I have a mobile application that accesses the Google Drive API, and my corresponding Google Cloud Platform project uses the ".auth/drive" scope. Several months ago, I went through the Google API verification process and Google approved the project. At that time, ".auth/drive" was a sensitive scope.

However, after this approval, Google changed the scope for ".auth/drive" from "sensitive" to "restricted". So far, my mobile app with the Google Drive API works fine, and I have received no notification of the scope change from Google. However, on the Google API verification site, it says "**All applications must be revalidated every year...**", and the app requires a security assessment, which Google assigns to each app into "tier" (Tier 2, Tier 3, etc.).

My question is, when will the review/verification process for the restricted scope happen (one year from last approval, one year from scope change, or rather randomly?), and what exactly is the process? I have gone through the verification process for the "sensitive" scope but have never done it for a "restricted" scope before. Any insight into this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Good question let me ask.  Although from what i know auth/drive was always a restricted scope.   What makes you think it was just sensitve?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  However, "./auth/drive" was "sensitive" scope up until early this year.  I was able to be verified of my GCP projects, one at end of last year & another early this year, around February with ".auth/drive" scope as "sensitive" scope.  Since then, when I checked later (after both are approved), the scope changed to "restricted" for both projects.  I am sure about this.